# What is considered a stepchild?

Tags: meaning

I believe a stepchild is a child to a former partner. So, if it's your former partner with someone else, right? If your former partner adopted a child? What if for some reason you have a child with your former partner? Is that your step child or your child? I don't really understand how stepchild is defined?

Comment: wait there's no one definition?

Comment: "a child of one's husband or wife by a previous marriage"  Why isn't it "from a previous marriage"?

Comment: 'Having a child _by_ someone' or '_by_ a relationship' is a perfectly standard usage, though 'with someone' and 'from a relationship' are probably more common nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

A stepchild is your partner's child from a former relationship.

For example if Gary marries Jane, and Jane already has a daughter named Alice, then Alice becomes Gary's stepdaughter.

Comment: what happens if Gary and Jane divorce, and Jane has another child with another person. Is that your step child too?

Comment: @Wisesequoia, practically, you would normally not have any personal relationship with a child your spouse has after you break up, you would not consider them a step child and there isn't,  AFAIK any word for that (non-)relationship.

Comment: If Gary and Jane divorce and Jane marries Henry then Alice also becomes Henry's step-daughter. Gary and Alice may consider their step-relationship to continue but then Alice would have two step-fathers. However if Jane and Henry have a daughter called Bella then Bella has no formal relationship to Gary even though she is Alice's half sister and may visit Gary with Alice.